# Need to understand pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

Below code i'm trying to perform pointer Arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *ptr = malloc(100);

    printf("base : %p\n", ptr);
    printf("\n");
    printf("base+1 : %p\n", ptr+1);

    ptr+= 100;
    *ptr = 90;
    printf("addr: %p val : %d\n", ptr, *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

## output:

```
base : 0x5621e46412a0

base+1 : 0x5621e46412a4
addr: 0x5621e4641430 val : 90
```

## question:

1. malloc (100); will it return 100 bytes ?
2. Here i'm not typecasting return addr of malloc,  BTW malloc will return void type correct how ptr+1 increments 4 byte ?
3. Now incrementing ptr+100, so 400 byte will get incremented correct ? also i can able to assign value with out segmentation fault how it works ?

Trying to understand how pointer arithmetic works in this case

Comment: Looks like your ptr++ moved the pointer by 4 bytes.  Looks like you're in a 32 bit environment.

Comment: If you want 100 _elements_ in `ptr`, you need: `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 100);` In _your_ code, you _only_ allocate space for `100 / sizeof(int)` elements --> 25 elements. The `malloc` arg is number of _bytes_ and not number of _elements_. It doesn't know what type of pointer gets its return value. Also, even with the corrected `malloc`, doing `ptr += 100; *ptr = 90;` is UB (undefined behavior) because you are one element past the end of the allocated area. UB means: may work [seemingly], may produce "funny" results, may segfault, etc.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

Answer (score 2):

> malloc (100); will it return 100 bytes ?

Yes. Or more precise: It will reserve 100 bytes for you and return the address of that memory area.
See [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

> Here i'm not typecasting return addr of malloc, BTW malloc will return void type correct how ptr+1 increments 4 byte ?

That is not correct. `malloc` does not return `void` but pointer to `void`. This is compatible with any pointer to any data without a cast.
After assigning to `ptr` it is a pointer to `int`. The increment only depends on the type of the pointer, i.e. `int`.

> Now incrementing ptr+100, so 400 byte will get incremented correct ? also i can able to assign value with out segmentation fault how it works ?

Correct (given that you seem to work with a 32bit system). That means you are illegally accessing memory you do not own and you are not supposed to access. This results in undefined behaviour. It can seem to work or crash.
Undefined behaviour also means it is not defined to cause a segfault.

See [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Re “This is compatible with”: Compatible has a technical meaning in the C standard. It essentially means two types can be completed to be the same type. E.g., `int a[]` and `int a[3]` are compatible because missing length in the former can be completed to be the same length as in the latter. `void` cannot be completed (by rule), so `void` is not compatible with any different type. `void *` and `int *` cannot be completed to be the same, so they are not compatible. Assignment implicitly converts, and `void *` can be converted to any pointer-to-object type.

Answer (score 0):

1. No; it will return a *pointer* to at least 100 bytes, or `NULL`.
2. No; it increments by `sizeof(*ptr)` which in this case is `sizeof(int)`. That could be a different value than 4. A ptr-to-void is assignment-compatible to any object pointer without a cast and in C it is best practice to not cast the malloc return value. Search this site for the reasons.
3. Not correct; it increments by `100*sizeof(*ptr)`. That could be a value other than 400. Writing through that pointer is *undefined behavior*, so anything could happen, including nothing noticeable.

To print pointer values, it is not sufficient to use the `%p` format specifier, the argument must be a pointer-to-void, so you must use `(void*)` casts as in

```
printf("base : %p\n", (void*)ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. malloc (100); will it return 100 bytes ?

`malloc(100)` will return either a pointer to where 100 bytes of memory has been reserved or a null pointer.

> 2. Here i'm not typecasting return addr of malloc,…

The simple assignment operator (`=`) automatically converts its right operand to the type of the left operand. When the left operand is a pointer, the right operand may be either of:

- a pointer to a compatible type or to `void` except that the right type may omit qualifiers that the left type has or
- a null pointer constant.

> BTW malloc will return void type correct how ptr+1 increments 4 byte ?

C does not “remember” that an address came from `malloc` with return type `void *`. When `ptr+1` is evaluated, the type of `ptr` is used for the arithmetic. The type of `ptr` is `int *`, so the arithmetic is performed in units of `int`.

> 3. Now incrementing ptr+100, so 400 byte will get incremented correct ?

Within the allocated space, adding *x* will add 4*x* bytes to the address, if the C implementation uses four bytes for `int`. Outside of the allocated space, the C standard does not define the behavior of pointer arithmetic. If the allocated space were 1000 bytes instead of 100, then `ptr+100` would calculate the address 400 bytes beyond the start.

> … also i can able to assign value with out segmentation fault how it works ?

Memory protect usually works in units of pages. If you use memory that is within a page you have access to, there is no segmentation fault even if it is not a place in the page you should be accessing the way you access it. Or, if you calculate an address incorrectly and the result is still a page you have access to, there is no segmentation fault. Memory protection does not absolutely prevent all address mistakes by a process, and dynamically allocated memory is likely to be in a region with many pages that the program is permitted to access.